# Направление элементов в CSS grid

Tags: css, css3, grid

Есть такая гридовская сетка:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

Когда элементов в сетке 10 и больше, то элементы продолжают появляться в том же направлении, что и появлялись.
Но я хочу изменить это, чтобы внизу появлялась как бы следующая сетка 3*3, в которой будут появляться элементы в таком же направлении, и при заполнении её заново появлялась новая сетка и т.д. . Не новый DOM элемент (я знаю как сделать это), а именно как на CSS это написать, если это возможно сделать на гридах

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("item");
  content.append(div);
  const items = content.querySelectorAll(".item");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Тогда получится, что в колонке ячейки будут идти в таком порядке: 1-2-3-10-11-12-19-... Это не кажется логичным.

Comment: @UModeLb :(((((

Comment: @UModeL а можно сетку 3*3 направо ставить? У меня что-то не получается. Я вроде поставил `grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr`, но ведёт оно себя, как будто это 1fr